# Does Monitor.TryEnter and lock() work together?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, thread-safety

I am looking at code that has been created and it uses a TryEnter in one method call and lock in others. So, like this:

```
private readonly object xmppLock = new object();

void f1() 
{
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(xmppLock))
    {
        try
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(xmppLock);
        }
    }
}

void f2()
{
    lock(xmppLock)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Is this okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lock will block until the resource is available

[TryEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.tryenter%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) will not do anything if it is already locked.

Depending on your needs you have to use one or the other.

In your case `f2()` will always do what ever it does no matter how long it takes. `f1()` will return immediately if there is lock contention

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is whether it is okay to **mix** `lock` and `Monitor.TryEnter`, with the same object. [See answers to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14377366/199364)

Answer (score 11):

`lock` is just syntax sugar for `Monitor.Enter`, so yes, it will work fine.

> [The Visual Basic SyncLock and C# lock statements use Monitor.Enter to take the lock and Monitor.Exit to release it. The advantage of using the language statements is that everything in the lock or SyncLock block is included in a Try statement.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf5de04k.aspx)

(That said, it's considered poor form to lock on something public like a `Type` object.)

Comment: This doesn't answer **TryEnter** which the OP uses

Comment: It's dead obvious that acquiring a lock using `TryEnter` in one place will work together with acquiring it using `Enter` in another place, so it's not worth dwelling on.

Answer (score 7):

Yes these two constructs will work together.  The C# `lock` keyword is just a thin wrapper over the `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.TryEnter` methods.

Note: I would absolutely avoid using a `Type` instance as the value to lock on.  Doing so is very fragile as it makes it very easy for two completely unrelated pieces of code to be unexpectedly locking on the same object.  This can lead to deadlocks.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer regarding typeof(). I had asked a different question regarding this as I didn't understand what it was doing as its not my code I am editing and I wanted to make sure I knew what was happening.