# Can lock and monitor be used on same object safely?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I have the following situation: I want to mutualy exclude access to an object.

So far I normaly would use a lock object

```
object lockObject = new object();
...

method1: lock(lockObject) { CODE1 }
```

Now I have also a method which can be called from another thread. It should not be blocked for unknown time, instead it should give an answer in a defined time.

In this case i would use a monitor, like

```
method2:
try{
   Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject , 20000, ref lockTaken);
   if (lockTaken) {CODE2}
}
catch(...){...}
finally
{
   if (lockTaken) Monitor.Exit(timerLock);
}
```

Now my question is: can lock and monitor be mixed in such a way if the lockobject is the same and mutually exclude each other, or would it be needed to change every lock to a monitor.

So would both times the same token be "locked", or would the monitor create another token for the object then the lock?

At a glimpse I cannot see that the aplication runs in code of both at the same time. But I don't know if any timing issues can exist, where CODE1 and CODE2 are executed in parallel.

Comment: I feel your pain; I often wish the `lock` keyword took a timeout somehow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
lock (sync)
{
   return World();
}
```

Would look along the lines of this in Intermediate Language.

```
L_0007: call void [mscorlib]System.Threading.Monitor::Enter(object)
L_000c: call int32 Hello::World()
L_0011: stloc.0 
L_0012: leave.s L_001b
L_0014: ldloc.1 
L_0015: call void [mscorlib]System.Threading.Monitor::Exit(object)
```

So it should be okay. They are technically equivalent.

Comment: note that recent versions of csc, when targeting .NET 4 or above, will have different IL to this

Comment: Thanks, true. Just did it for rough illustration.

Answer (score 9):

> can lock and monitor be mixed in such a way if the lockobject is the same and mutually exclude each other

Yes, that is totally safe and it will work.

The `lock { }` statement is rewritten to  calls to Monitor.Enter() and Monitor.Exit(). It's just short-hand, very similar to the `using() {}` statement.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664735%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
 lock (x) ...
```

becomes

```
System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(x);
try {
   ...
}
finally {
   System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(x);
}
```

And as per the comment, in Fx4 and later it can use `Monitor.TryEnter()` . But the simple version above answers your question.

Comment: Or Monitor.TryEnter when targeting .NET 4+.